# alert() in javascript while using apigee's JavaScript policy

Tags: apigee

I am trying to implement `alert()` in java script while using `apigee's` JavaScript policy.

**Below is my javascript policy:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Javascript async="false" continueOnError="false" enabled="true" 
          timeLimit="200" name="javascript-1">
    <DisplayName>JavaScript-1</DisplayName>
    <ResourceURL>jsc://javascript-1</ResourceURL>
</Javascript>
```

**javascript-1 file:**

```
alert('1212');
```

However I am getting the below error.

**Error Code:**

> {"fault":"{\"detail\":{\"errorcode\":\"steps.javascript.ScriptExecutionFailed\"},\"faultstring\":\"Execution
>   of javascript-1 failed with error: Javascript runtime error:
>   \\"ReferenceError: \\"alert\\" is not defined. (javascript_1#59).
>   at line 59 \\"\"}"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JavaScript alert function is not available in Apigee's Edge JavaScript policy. alert() is a user-interface function that creates a message box. There is no user interface in an API facade, and alert is not supported when using the trace tool.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to debug your script, there is another way. You can assign any variable or literal to a flow variable using `context.setVariable("debugVar", "Hello there");`  That way the value will shown on Debug view of Apigee and help you debug. You can later on clean it up.

Answer (score 2):

Another, not well-known, function you can call is **print**, as in:

print("Hello from my script");

All output from print calls will be logged when you are Tracing an API call.  When in the Trace tool, you will see this output under "Standard Output".

It's a great debugging tool.

Answer (score 0):

Another way that you can aproach is use console.log(message) in your javascript code which will output the 'message' to the console output in the developer tools in Chrome or Firefox.